# Can the Victory Timer be Shortened for the Age of Empires II "King of the Hill" Game Mode?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

**Can the victory timer be shortned for the Age of Empires II "King of the Hill game mode?** I would like to be able to play faster/shorter games, but with the timer set for as long as it is, I get bored waiting for the clock to reach zero while the AI fails to break through my defenses.

I checked the game's [wiki](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/King_of_the_Hill), but only found a description of the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept searching and I found it! A very kind person shared their own created solution at RTS Sanctuary in [this thread](http://www.rts-sanctuary.com/Age-Of-Empires-3/showtopic=232542). The answer is **YES!** and the mod can be downloaded [here](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwIdKMx3WwRgWVYzYlZJZGlQM1U&authuser=0) or from the original post.

**Note:** I couldn't find it earlier because I didn't realize that the title is actually *Age of Empires*, **not** *Age of Kings*. Once I had the right title it was a quick find.